# How to Sort multiple elements of different type in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a scenario to sort a column having multiple type of elements, drop-down  list and string(HTML) type.
I want to sort that particular column containing drop-down list and HTML type of data.
This is what I Have tried using

"orderDataType": "dom-select" and "sType": 'html'

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function (settings, col) 
{
    return this.api().column(col, 
{ 
   order: 'index' }).nodes().map(function (td, i) {
        return $('select', td).val();
    });
}
```

But only the string is sorting.
The drop down list is not sorting.

Please give me suggestions